# How to continuously draw canvas wave using dynamic array in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is my problems

1) I have dynamic y array data ,using that array how to continuously draw the wave.

if Y array data complete use same y array data to continue.

2)  sound auto play in that array value is 143.if i stop that not stopping.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="160" style="background-color: black;"></canvas>
        <script type='text/javascript'>


            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle ="#dbbd7a";
            ctx.fill();

            var fps = 1000;
            var n = 0;

            var myAudio = new Audio("http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/AFsp/M1F1-uint8WE-AFsp.wav"); // buffers automatically when created
            myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                this.currentTime = 0;
                this.play();
            }, false);

            animate();
            function animate() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    ctx.lineWidth="2";
                    ctx.strokeStyle='green';
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                // y axixs Data

                var Ydata = [
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                            148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                          ];

                    // Drawing code goes here
                    n += 1.5;
                    if (n > 200) {
                        n = 0;
                    }
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    for (var x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                        if(Ydata[x] == '143')
                           myAudio.play();

                        ctx.lineTo(x, Ydata[x]);
                    }
                ctx.stroke();

            }, 1000/fps);
        }

        function stopAlarm()
        {
            myAudio.pause();
            myAudio.currentTime = 0;

        }

        </script>
        <button type="button" name="Stop" id="Stop" onclick="stopAlarm();">Stop Alarm</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am downvoting your question...here's why:  (1). Your question fails to clearly explain your problem. (2). When asked for clarifying information, you responded without giving that necessary information. (3) Even allowing for the likelihood that English is not your first language, you responded rudely to someone who was trying to help you with an answer...That person felt offended enough to delete his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear to me what you are trying to do, but checking quickly you code, I could find an error, if n can be 199, and you have 140 elements in Ydata, in some point you could have an exception,

If you are trying to have "animate" in some type of loop you should try to change setTimeOut by setInterval:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: why is this not working for you? Could you add a bit more of information?