# How to move canvas left to right with that data array?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Using same data array every time canvas moving but not continuously?

How to move canvas line left to right with that data array ?

if data array is completed use same data to continuously

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="160" style="background-color: black;"></canvas>
        <script type='text/javascript'>


            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle ="#dbbd7a";
            ctx.fill();

            var fps = 1000;
            var n = 0;

            drawWave();
            var data = [
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
            ];

            function drawWave() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(drawWave);
                    ctx.lineWidth="2";
                    ctx.strokeStyle='green';
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                    // Drawing code goes here
                    n += 1.5;
                    if (n > 200) {
                        n = 0;
                    }
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    for (var x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                        ctx.lineTo(x, data[x]);
                    }
                    ctx.stroke();

                }, 1000/fps);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't really understand what you mean

Comment: i want to move wave left to right continuously with same array data? now it is going repeatedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are some problems with your code:**

*The reason for your non-continuous delay at the end of your animation loop...*

Your array has 140 elements but your code is trying to plot 200 elements. The delay is your code trying to plot (200-140) non-existent array elements.

```
If(n>=data.length)     // not n>200 (there are only 140 data elements to process!)
```

Using setTimeout with a fps interval of 1000 is not achievable (60fps is a practical maximum).

```
Var fps=60;   // not fps=1000 is too fast to be achieved
```

You are incrementing n by 1.5 each time.  This will skip some of your data elements.  If this is not your intention you should instead increment n by 1.

```
n+=1;    // not n+=1.5 which will skip some of your data[] elements
```

You are clearing the canvas and completely redrawing the wave in each animation loop.  This works, but instead, keep your previous canvas and add the additional line to plot your next [x,y].  Only clear after you have drawn all your data points.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(n-1,data[n-1]);
ctx.lineTo(n,data[n]);
ctx.stroke();
```

Here is a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/vPXkm/

**[Addition based on OP's new information]**

After your further clarification, *I might understand what you desire*

I think you want to have a wave pattern originate new plots from the left part of the canvas and push the existing data to the right using animation.  After all x,y are plotted from your data[] source, you want the plots to repeat at the beginning of data[].

So here is how you do that:

- Resize the canvas to twice the width of your data[].
- Plot your data across the canvas twice. (data[0-140] and then data[0-140] again).
- Convert the canvas to an image.
- Resize the canvas to the width of your data[].
- Animate the image across the canvas with an increasing offsetX to give the illusion of movement.
- When you run out of image, reset the offset.
- This reset appears seamless since the image is repeated twice.

Here is new code and another Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qpWrj/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="560" height="160" style="background-color: black;"></canvas>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var data = [
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,148
            ];

            var fps = 30;
            var offsetX=-data.length*2;
            var waveImage;

            createWaveImage();

            function createWaveImage(){

                // make the canvas double data.length
                // and fill it with a background color
                canvas.width=data.length*2;
                ctx.fillStyle ="#dbbd7a";
                ctx.strokeStyle="green";
                ctx.lineWidth=2;
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

                // plot data[] twice
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(0,data[0]);
                for(var x=1; x<data.length*2; x++){
                    var n=(x<data.length)?x:x-data.length;
                    ctx.lineTo(x,data[n]);
                }
                ctx.stroke();

                // convert the canvas to an image
                waveImage=new Image();
                waveImage.onload=function(){
                    // resize the canvas to data.length
                    canvas.width=data.length;
                    // refill the canvas background color
                    ctx.fillStyle ="#dbbd7a";
                    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                    // animate this wave image across the canvas
                    drawWave();
                }
                waveImage.src=canvas.toDataURL();
            }


            // animate the wave image in an endless loop
            function drawWave() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(drawWave);

                    // Draw the wave image with an increasing offset
                    // so it appears to be moving
                    ctx.drawImage(waveImage,offsetX++,0);

                    // if we've run out of image, reset the offsetX
                    if((offsetX)>0){
                        offsetX=-data.length;
                    }

                }, 1000/fps);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mark.but i want to move that wave not repeat that wave .. move forward using same data always ...

Comment: Kindly explain better--very, very, very hard to understand what you need!!  Do you want the wave to animate, but always have the front of the wave not go off the right side of the canvas?  If I don't understand, please explain...

Comment: Yes Moving front alway

Comment: I have added to my answer based on your additional info.

Comment: I though I had a deja-vu moment but then I remembered (particularly the patience part :) ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287832/how-to-continuously-draw-canvas-wave-using-dynamic-array-in-html5

Comment: Your question asks about fixed data--not dynamic data.  You can modify my first answer to work for dynamic data.

Comment: Again...dynamic data was not your question.  You can modify my first answer to work for dynamic data and you can modify my first answer to add new plots from the left instead of to the right.  It is your turn to do some coding.  If you run into trouble, show your code in a new question.

Comment: mark can you please help me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346098/how-to-draw-ecg-monitor-in-canvas-using-html5

Comment: BigBadaboom has given you a good answer on that followup question. Cheers!