# How to draw ecg monitor in canvas using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am  try is to draw ecg system in using canvas html5.

Almost i am near to complete my wave is moving ,but not continuously it is repeating,But i want to draw the wave is move left to right continuously?

below link is example.

Ex:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuwBfSpVEgw

i am getting y data every 1 sec.

Data Ex:

```
var ydata = [
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                    148,149,149,150,150,150,143,82,82,82,82,82,82,82,
                ];
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="160" style="background-color: black;"></canvas>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#dbbd7a";
            ctx.fill();

            var fps = 60;
            var n = 1;


            var data = [
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, ];


            drawWave();

            function drawWave() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    requestAnimationFrame(drawWave);
                    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';

                    // Drawing code goes here
                    n += 1;
                    if (n >= data.length) {
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        n = 1;
                    }
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(n - 1, data[n - 1]);
                    ctx.lineTo(n, data[n]);
                    ctx.stroke();

                }, 1000 / fps);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try calling `drawWave()` recursively?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get it to look like the video, don't clear the frame at the end of each pass, just clear it to the right of the end of your path.

```
                // Drawing code goes here
                n += 1;
                if (n >= data.length) {
                    n = 1;
                }
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(n - 1, data[n - 1]);
                ctx.lineTo(n, data[n]);
                ctx.stroke();

                ctx.clearRect(n+1, 0, 10, canvas.height);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Shp4X/

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: thanks Big.Here is my small doubt if y data coming every 1 second that time ,how can write  can you please help me on that?

Comment: +1 @BigBadaboom: You did a nice adjustment for the refreshing-moving bar.  To the OP: If you want your demo to plot 1 new Y value every second, you can change the fps value from 60 to 1 (but that seems kind of slow.)

Comment: The max fps is 60, so you will need to draw about 2 Y's per frame to complete 140 Y's in 60 frames.  You could do 2Y,2Y,3Y (and repeat this pattern) which would give you 140 Y's per second.

Comment: ok mark .if y values getting from ajax call every 1 sec .how to draw that.Can you please give sample @markE

Comment: If you get a packet of 140 Y's every 1 second, don't bother animating the result...Just show all 140 immediately and then wait for the next packet to arrive.

Comment: @BigBadaboom I have small doubt if y data coming socket call that is not animating can you please help me on this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660275/how-to-rendering-socket-data-in-canvas-html5

Answer (score 1):

```
var EcgData=[];    
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    speed = 1,
    scanBarWidth = 20,
    i=0,
    data = EcgData[0].split(','),
    color='#00ff00';
var px = 0;
var opx = 0;
var py = h/2;
var opy = py;
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,-1,0,h);

drawWave();

function drawWave() {
     px += speed;
     ctx.clearRect( px,0, scanBarWidth, h);
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo( opx,  opy);
     ctx.lineJoin= 'round';
     py=(data[++i>=data.length? i=0 : i++]/450+10);
     ctx.lineTo(px, py);
     ctx.stroke();
     opx = px;
     opy = py;
     if (opx > w) {px = opx = -speed;}

     requestAnimationFrame(drawWave);
 }
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/majidagt/hc18mvbw/

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` only runs its callback once.
You never told your code to run more than once.

You should call `requestAnimationFrame()` to run your animation every time the browser renders a frame.
You will then need to check how much time has passed since the previous frame and update the animation by the appropriate distance.

Comment: I am already using same ..can you give me answer some more clear?

Comment: @purBin: You shouldn't be calling `setTimeout()` at all.

Comment: I am calling function drawWave() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    requestAnimationFrame(drawWave); check once in my code...

Comment: @purBin: The whole point of `requestAnimationFrame` is to re-render on every frame.  Don't call `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @SLaks: setTimeout is being used in combination with requestAnimationFrame to throttle RAF to a specific frame rate.  That method seems reasonable for a demo, but yes, a real-world ecg should use time-difference to precisely calculate the next X.

Answer (score 0):

I created the easiest to use web component for displaying data from bluetooth heart rate monitor or external api.  All you need to do is call `bang()` on every appearing beat.

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<ecg-line></ecg-line>';
ecgLine((bang) => setInterval(() => bang(), 1000));
```

The source code is published [here](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/ecg-line-webcomponent). I think it looks much better than the presented alternatives

[image]