# How to rendering Socket data in canvas html5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, websocket

1) How to rendering Socket data in canvas html5?

Using  constant data i rending canvas.

When i am getting data from socket that is not rending like above one

1) socket data coming like same above example every 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I think; your data array should be outside of 'drawWave' method as your fiddle ex and you should call 'drawWave' method just once in 'socket.on'. After a call of 'drawWave'. you should change your data array at 'socket.on' , not at 'drawWave'.

Could you try that?

```
    var data = [];
    var drawWaveCaught=false;
    socket.on('canvasData', function (incomeData) {
        console.log(incomeData);
        data = JSON.parse("[" + incomeData + "]");
        if(!drawWaveCaught){
            drawWaveCaught = true;
            that.drawWave(); 

        } 
    });
function drawWave() {
        requestAnimFrame(drawWave);
        var n = 0;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        //alert(id);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#dbbd7a";
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.lineWidth = "2";
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
        // Drawing code goes here
        for(n=1;n<=data.length;n++)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(n - 1, data[n - 1] * 2);
            ctx.lineTo(n, data[n] * 2);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.clearRect(n + 1, 0, 10, canvas.height);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Using my code when socket result coming canvas draw perfectly ,But that is rendering like my fiddle example.